# PubNub message format in callbacks

Tags: pubnub

When I get a callback, I get an object passed in. The content of the object seems to have two levels of 'encoding'. It always seems to consist of 3 basic elements:

- My data
- Timestamp
- Channel

in that order so `[0]=data`, `[1] = timestamp` and `[2] = channel` where `timestamp` and `channel` are PubNub supplied strings. My data comes in as a JSON object (string, numeric, or object etc.) in the first item returned.

**But** nowhere can I find in the documentation that this structure (i.e. 3 incoming 'objects') is actually defined. If it **is** defined then I should be able to map a type or class to it, to better handle it, i.e. cast it to a `'PubNubMessage' class [object data; string timestamp; string channel;]`?

Can someone please point me at a document where this message format is actually defined?

Comment: I believe the real confusion is that this can be either a JSONObject or a JSONArray. I think the plan is to make this a more formally defined class in v4.x of the PubNub Java SDK. I am going to have the Java engineering team review for further comment.

Comment: Can you provide some details, like some sample code, the APIs you are using and some examples as well as the SDK/version you are using to support@pubnub.com - thanks.

Comment: Did you ever contact PubNub Support?